# how to random dc?

Tags: image-processing, block, dct, ssim

i want to make an image scrambling using DCT in matlab. i used a grayscale image. i want to random dc with random value. how to set the DC coefficient of each block to a random
value `0-255` and leave all others??these are steps for experiment:Divide a gray image into `8x8` blocks;Perform DCT on each block;set the DC coefficient of each block to a random
value `0-255` and leave all others;Perform inverse DCT and restore the image;Compare the restored image with the original one
by SSIM.
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is "how to set the DC coefficient of each block to a (given) value...". So the procedure you mention (DCT, set DC coefficient, then iDCT) should work. You would use Matlab's *dct2* and *idct2* functions.

However, from the DCT definition, the DC coefficient is the sum of the values of the pixels in each of your blocks; setting it to a random value and taking the inverse transform will produce a block that would be different from the original one only by a constant. That's no surprise because you are just changing the **DC level**. So you could skip the DCT/iDCT and directly add or subtract a random value to all pixels in each block.

*But* you can see that each block would look like the original one, except for a different luminosity; also, the boundaries between blocks would be quite visible, so the scrambling method could be easily reversed.